# Почему внутренняя функция декоратора запускается без ее вызова?

Tags: python

```
def decorator(func):
    def inner():
        print("start decorator")
        func()
        print("end decorator")
    return inner

@decorator
def function():
    print("Start function")
    print("End function")

function()
```

Почему функция inner запускается без ее вызова inner(), и как проходит цепочка действий при вызове декоратора?

Насколько я знаю запись @decorator равносильно function = decorator(function), и при вызове функции function() мы вызываем decorator() с аргументом function, но почему запускается inner()? Если мы по сути просто возвращаем на нее адрес >return inner
И почему нельзя записать код без внутренней функции следующим образом:

```
def decorator(func):
    print("start decorator")
    func()
    print("end decorator")
```

Comment: `function` — это и есть внутренняя функция `inner`, которую вернул декоратор. Когда вы пишете `function()` — вы вызываете внутреннюю функцию

Comment: «при вызове функции function() мы вызываем decorator()» — нет, декоратор вызывается сразу в момент его использования, а переменная `function` будет содержать то значение, которое вернул декоратор — в вашем случае она содержит функцию `inner`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы было совсем понятно, я добавил ещё печати и немного её переобозвал:

```
def decorator(func):
    print("start decorator")
    def inner():
        print("start inner")
        func()
        print("end inner")
    print("end decorator")
    return inner

print('call decorator')
@decorator
def function():
    print("Start function")
    print("End function")

print('call function')
function()
```

Вывод:

```
call decorator
start decorator
end decorator
call function
start inner
Start function
End function
end inner
```

Понятно, что происходит? Декоратор вызвался и вернул обёртку над функцией. Когда мы потом вызвали функцию - мы на самом деле вызвали эту обёртку, которая в свою очередь вызвала функцию. В этом суть работы декораторов.

А теперь попробуем предложенный вами альтернативный вариант:

```
def decorator(func):
    print("start decorator")
    func()
    print("end decorator")

print('call decorator')
@decorator
def function():
    print("Start function")
    print("End function")

print('call function')
function()
```

Вывод:

```
call decorator
start decorator
Start function
End function
end decorator
call function
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-89751d3d1e3a> in <module>
     11 
     12 print('call function')
---> 13 function()

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Вот незадача. Во-первых при вызове декоратора декорируемая функция тоже сразу вызвалась, ещё до того, как мы хотели её сами вызвать. А во-вторых, когда мы всё же захотели вызвать функцию - она не вызвалась, потому что декоратор ничего не вернул, а значит он вернул `None`, переменная `function` содержит этот `None` и не может быть вызвана как функция. Короче, всё сломалось.

Мораль:

- пользуйтесь отладочной печатью, это просто и полезно
- не бойтесь экспериментировать и проверять гипотезы